# Apache Redhat list how many times /foo/ was hit from command line

Tags: apache, access-log

so far I have not been able to find an answer online or in any book. I would like to **count** how many times **/foo/** was hit on my site. If anyone could help, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter this on a command line:

```
grep -c '/foo/' /var/log/httpd/access_log
```

This will show the number of counts of "/foo/" inside of your apache acess log file.

There are more access log files:

access_log.2  access_log.4
access_log.1  access_log.3  access_log.5

If you want to see the result from older entries, then you can use

```
grep -c '/foo/' /var/log/httpd/access_log*
```

Result:

```
/var/log/httpd/access_log:46
/var/log/httpd/access_log.1:85
/var/log/httpd/access_log.2:46
/var/log/httpd/access_log.3:103
/var/log/httpd/access_log.4:70
/var/log/httpd/access_log.5:177
```

The path depends on your Redhat version.

http://www.itninja.com/blog/view/mysql-and-apache-profile-log-path-locations

Comment: Thank you Franz Holzinger, this seemed to work. I did not have a count with "/foo/" but then used "/foo' and counted some hits. Is there a reason for this ?

Comment: Which result does `grep '/foo' /var/log/httpd/access_log` give?